# what are the difference in ruby methods

Tags: ruby, operator-overloading

What are the difference of the following method and how do it function/works?

> method(x)

```
def method(x)
  # some codes
end
```

> method=(x)

```
def method=(x)
  # some codes
end
```

> ==(x)

```
def ==(x)
  # some codes
end
```

I kwow how `method(x)` works, it is a method with a required parameter. But I don't know how other methods works and when and how to use. Also I don't know the difference. Can someone explain it for me?

Thanks!

Comment: The `method=` is a naming convention used for setter methods (`attr_writer` type things). Basically, a private instance variables value can be changed using a setter. The `==` is an existing method in the standard Ruby library. It's a comparator conditional. But when you write a method for it like you are in your post, it's most likely an attempt to redefine it. Ruby allows you to change existing methods for your own needs. This is called monkey patching

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "what is the difference"? What do you mean by "how it works"? Are you asking how methods are represented internally in YARV? Also, what does this question have to do with [tag:ruby-on-rails]? And are you asking about [tag:ruby-on-rails-3] or [tag:ruby-on-rails-4], it doesn't make sense to ask about both, really?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, they are all just methods with different names:

```
class Test
  def foo(x)
    puts "foo #{x}"
  end

  def bar=(x)
    puts "bar #{x}"
  end

  def ==(x)
    puts "== #{x}"
  end
end

Test.new.foo(42)  # foo 42
Test.new.bar=(42) # bar 42
Test.new.==(42)   # == 42
```

---

As for how they are used:

Idiomatically, `bar=` is used to set the instance variable `bar` of the object at hand to the value passed. It's basically what you would call a setter method in java.

```
class Test
  def bar=(value)
    @bar = value
  end
end

test = Test.new
test.bar=(42)
test.inspect # => "#<Test:0x00559a90b06c80 @bar=42>"
```

Idiomatically, `==` is used to tell if the current instance is equal to the argument passed. Therefore, it would be most appropriate for the method to return a boolean value. You can think of `equals` in java.

```
class Point2D
  attr_reader :x, :y

  def initialize(x, y)
    @x = x
    @y = y
  end

  def ==(other)
    @x == other.x and @y == other.y
  end
end

Point2D.new(3, 4).==(Point2d.new(1, 2)) # => false
points = [Point2D.new(3, 4), Point2D.new(5, 4), Point2D.new(6, 6), Point2D.new(3, 4)]
points.count Point2D.new(3, 4) # => 2
```

---

There are a few other differences with ordinary methods:

- There is syntax sugar for `bar=` so you can put any amount of whitespaces between `bar` and `=` or `=` and the argument
- There is sugar for `==` so you can omit the invocation `.` and put any amount of spaces between the instance and the `==` or `==` and the argument
- `bar=` will always return the value that was passed
- `bar=` can be invoked on an instance even if it's declared `private`

Answer (score 3):

If you understand how the first one works, then the other two work the same way.

In Ruby, everything is an object and method invocation is essentially about sending messages to that object. By making/allowing the method name a bit more like operators (`==` or the assignment method) you get the feel that it's some in built Ruby native logic, rather they all just operate by finding the first implementation up the class inheritance hierarchy.

You will find equality method implementation up the class hierarchy somewhere up in Object class unless you override it somewhere in the middle.

Assignment methods are created for you by `attr_writers` (or via `attr_accessor`). Ruby understands `self.blah = 1` as `self.blah=(1)` so to speak.

Research the `send` method in Ruby to understand messaging.

Boils down to

```
self.send("method",123)
self.send("method=",x)
self.send("==", somethingelse)
```